# How to set the style of a single element with event.target.style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, target

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import gridd from '../wordpuzzle.json'; // imports a 4x4 matrix


const WordsGrid = (props) => {

    
        const handlePressed = (e) => {
            console.log(e.target.style) // why it shows undefined even if I have set it below?
            e.target.style.backgroundColor='black'  // does nothing
        }
        

        return  (
            <View >
                <>
                {gridd.square.map(row => 
                
                    <View>

                        {row.map(letter => (
                            <>
                            <Pressable style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} onPress={(e) => handlePressed(e)}>
                                <Text >
                                    {letter}
                                </Text>
                            </Pressable>
                            
                            </>
                        ))}

                    </View>)}
                </>
            </View>

        );
}


export default WordsGrid;
```

Why e.target.style shows undefined, even if I have set the style below?

How to change a single (since I am putting there a little bit of them, because of the double for loop) Pressable item when pressed?

Comment: console.log(e.terget.style) // why it shows undefined even if I have set it below? "target" is mispelled

Comment: @ControlAltDel no, I mispelled in this post. If I write correctly in code, it shows undefined.

Comment: @ControlAltDel if I write `e.target.style.backgroundColor="black"`  it says `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'black'')`

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code:

- `onPress` callback's parameter is of type [`PressEvent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressevent) and does not have `e.target.style`.
- Even if it does have it, manipulating the style, which is the DOM element's attribute directly in React is not a good idea. (I know it's React Native but it's React too.)

Proper way of doing it is to add a state that changes upon pressing the `Pressable`, which in turn updates the style of the element through a classname.

As you have an array of `Pressable`s, your state also needs to be an array-ish variable, I suggest an object with a unique key of row and column indexes. Pseudo-code:

```js
const [readState, setReadState] = useState({});

// ...

handlePress = (index) => {
  const newReadState = { ...readState };
  newReadState[index] = true;
  setReadState(newReadState);
}

// ...

{gridd.square.map((row, rowIndex) =>
  <View>
    {row.map((letter, colIndex) => (
      <Pressable className={readState[`${rowIndex}${colIndex}`] ? 'read' : 'unread'} onPress={() => handlePress(`${rowIndex}${colIndex}`)}>

//...

// define styles for "read" and "unread" classnames here
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I don't know if I have understood well how to do it via classname. can you tell me how?

Comment: @Allexj see edit.

Comment: @Allexj did it answer your question?